# How do I escape special characters in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML being output from my XSLT

Current output

```
<stem>
    <text>
        <p style="white-space: pre-wrap">
            <span style="font-size:11;">How much would it cost to buy an Apple &amp; Pear if it's a Saturday?</span>
        </p>
    </text>
</stem>
```

Desired output

```
<stem>
    <text>
        <p style="white-space: pre-wrap">
            <span style="font-size:11;">How much would it cost to buy an Apple &amp; Pear if it&apos;s a Saturday?</span>
        </p>
    </text>
</stem>
```

I tried disable-output-escaping="no" but it had no effect:

I'm using

```
<xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="no"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Escaping of ampersands should happen automatically without doing anything special. Apostrophes may not be escaped if they are in a place where they don't have to be escaped (such as in your example). What is the output you are currently getting?

Comment: I just had a look and my input was wrong for the & its actually &amp; and that's fine - its the apostrophe I want converting - are you saying it won't do this?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. Escaping of `'`, `"`, and `>` is somewhat XSLT processor dependant. What processor are you using? Is there a particular reason you need the apostrophes escaped?

Comment: I'm using SAXON - my input software - place where the output xml is going (not got a lot of control of this) takes an ' and makes and makes &apos; but if I input &apos; it makes an ' which is what I wan't

Comment: Don't do this. There is no need to escape the apostrophe, it's absolutely fine to have it in literal form. (Corollary: If something breaks because there's a literal apostrophe in your XML, fix *that* part of the system, not the XML!)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using XSLT 2 (as your use of Saxon suggests) there is a feature
called [character maps](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#character-maps) to fine-tune how your output is serialized. To
serialize all apostrophes as `&apos;` use:

```
<xsl:character-map name="escape-apos">
    <xsl:output-character character="&apos;" string="&amp;apos;"/>
</xsl:character-map>

<xsl:output method="xml" use-character-maps="escape-apos"/>
```

Comment: And what about XSLT1?